# Recommend IDE for C++(Windows)?

Tags: c++, ide

I was originally going to use CLion because I use JetBrains' Pycharm, however, I came to the realization that it was not free like Pycharm after downloading it.

So, any recommendations? I guess I should mention that I would like it to be free. I realize that I should probably look it up but I feel it would be more beneficial to ask you lovely people.

Comment: What platform will it run on?

Comment: @rrirower by platform do you mean OS? If so I plan to run it on windows 10

Comment: There are many Windows 10 platforms: x86, x86-64, ARM, ARM64... it's not only about the OS

Answer (score 3):

[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/ide/) is free and supports many different languages.

For C/C++ development, make sure you download the [IDE for C/C++](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-03/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) Community is FREE and widely used by many developers.  It supports other languages besides C++ and includes an integrated debugger.  I've been using it for several years without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

[Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/) is an excellent free, Open Source IDE for C/C++ and Fortran. It supports multiple tool chains. It runs on Linux, Mac, Windows.

I can strongly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

**Visual Studio Code**

Visual Studio Code is an open-source and light IDE for c/c++. It is made by Microsoft. I recommend it because it is easy to use and it doesn't require large space. You just need to install the c/c++ extension after the installation of the visual studio code.

Visual Studio is a great choice but it requires larger space and runs slow on low-end computers.

Answer (score 1):

Sory, my coment from previos answer was a bit incorect, the old Dev-C++ is really dead, but there is a new version called [Embarcadero Dev-C++](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/dev-cpp?aldSet=en-GB). It is stil free and open source like its predecesor. This is also an IDE with minimal HD use which I know and it can be used as portable IDE even with compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Dev-C++.

As a suggestion, for some it is more convenience not to use an IDE at all. Try Notepad2 + MinGW.

Comment: Dev-C++ is dead for a long time.

Comment: @convert I thought it's still updating, since by the last time I used it, the version of g++ in that is very recent, and I haven't any problems coding.         Update: I saw your answer after sending the comment :)